# Postgres pg_trgm - why ordering by similarity is very slow

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have table `Users` with column `displayName (text)` and `pg_trgm gin index` on this column.

```
CREATE INDEX "Users-displayName-pg-trgm-index"
  ON "Users"
  USING gin
  ("displayName" COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT "User"."id"
    ,"User"."displayName"
    ,"User"."firstName"
    ,"User"."lastName"
    ,"User"."email"
    ,"User"."password"
    ,"User"."isVerified"
    ,"User"."isBlocked"
    ,"User"."verificationToken"
    ,"User"."birthDate"
    ,"User"."gender"
    ,"User"."isPrivate"
    ,"User"."role"
    ,"User"."coverImageUrl"
    ,"User"."profileImageUrl"
    ,"User"."facebookId"
    ,"User"."deviceType"
    ,"User"."deviceToken"
    ,"User"."coins"
    ,"User"."LocaleId"
    ,"User"."createdAt"
    ,"User"."updatedAt"
FROM "Users" AS "User"
WHERE (similarity("User"."displayName", 'John') > 0.2)
ORDER BY similarity("User"."displayName", 'John')
    ,"User"."id" ASC LIMIT 25;
```

Query above takes `~200ms` to return results. When I remove

```
ORDER BY similarity("User"."displayName", 'John')
```

and order just by `id` then query speeds up to `30ms`.

I am querying on table with `50k` users.

Here is explain analyze: http://explain.depesz.com/s/lXC

For some reason I don't see any index usage (`gin pg_trgm` on `displayName`)

---

It seems that when I replace line

```
WHERE (similarity("User"."displayName", 'John') > 0.2)
```

with

```
WHERE ("User"."displayName" % 'John')
```

query is super-fast - can anyone tell me why? I thought that `%` operator just checks if similarity(...) is greater than treshold... so what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't use indexes for function, it uses indexes only for operators.

The query that orders by similarity() calls that function for every row and then orders the rows.

The query that uses the `%` uses the index and runs similarity function on those that match (no index only scans for functions).

If you want to order by least similarity (as in the question) those that have similarity greater than 0.2 you should use the [distance operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) `<->`.

Like so:

```
WHERE "User"."displayName" <-> 'John' < 0.8
ORDER BY "User"."displayName" <-> 'John' DESC
```

The distance is 1- similarity hence 0.8

Comment: "PostgreSQL doesn't use indexes for function, it uses indexes only for operators." Are you saying that you can't create functional index in Postgres?

Comment: @ConsiderMe Perhaps it should be rephrased. PG does allow you to create indexes on expressions but that can't be used with functions like those in the questions.

Answer (score 7):

In my experience GIST index has been working better / faster for similarity ordering.

In this example I'm having customer table with ~500k rows.

```
select *,similarity(coalesce(details::text,'') || coalesce(name,''),'9') 
  from customer 
  order by (coalesce(details::text,'') || coalesce(name,'')) <-> '9' 
  asc limit 50;
```

Without any index query takes around 8,5s with query plan:

```
                              QUERY PLAN                                          
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=47687.03..47687.16 rows=50 width=1144)
   ->  Sort  (cost=47687.03..49184.52 rows=598995 width=1144)
         Sort Key: (((COALESCE((details)::text, ''::text) ||
                     (COALESCE(name, ''::character varying))::text) <-> '9'::text))
         ->  Seq Scan on customer  (cost=0.00..27788.85 rows=598995 width=1144)
(4 rows)
```

When adding GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON customer USING gin ((coalesce(details::text,'') || coalesce(name,'')) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Nothing happens. Query plan still looks the same and query still takes around 8.5 seconds to complete. No index is used for ordering.

After creating GIST index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON customer USING gist ((coalesce(details::text,'') || coalesce(name,'')) gist_trgm_ops);
```

Query takes around 240ms and query plan shows index being used

```
                     QUERY PLAN                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..10.19 rows=50 width=1144)
   ->  Index Scan using customer_expr_idx1 on customer  (cost=0.42..117106.73 rows=598995 width=1144)
     Order By: ((COALESCE((details)::text, ''::text) || 
                (COALESCE(name, ''::character varying))::text) <-> '9'::text)
(3 rows)
```

Just for curiosity rows returned looks like this:

```
   id   |           name           |        details         | similarity 
--------+--------------------------+------------------------+------------
     25 | Generic Company (9) Inc. |                        |  0.0909091
    125 | Generic Company (9) Inc. |                        |  0.0909091
 268649 | 9bg1ubTCYo7mMcDaHmCC     | { "fatty": "McDaddy" } |  0.0294118
 470217 | 9hSXtDmW9cXvKk4Q6McD     | { "fatty": "McDaddy" } |  0.0285714
 180775 | 9pRPi1w9nqV9999g2ceo     | { "fatty": "McDaddy" } |  0.0285714
 162931 | 9qMyYbWNJLZdv7uYYbOl     | { "fatty": "McDaddy" } |  0.0285714
 176961 | 9ow1NcTjAmCDyRsapDl4     | { "fatty": "McDaddy" } |  0.0285714
   ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't add comment to [Jakub Kania](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28546686/5448990) 's answer. I think for the following query:

```sql
WHERE "User"."displayName" <-> 'John' < 0.8
ORDER BY "User"."displayName" <-> 'John' DESC
```

indexes will not be used too.

You can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT set_limit(0.2);
...
WHERE "User"."displayName" % 'John'
ORDER BY "User"."displayName" <-> 'John' DESC
```